# Proxy server with dynamic routes

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I would like to proxy requests for a subdomain to a free backend server. Every subdomain has several related backendservers:

e.g.

```
sub1.example.com => (192.168.0.1:8000, 192.168.0.2:9000, 192.168.0.3:10000)
sub2.example.com => (192.168.0.1:8001, 192.168.0.2:9001, 192.168.0.3:10001)
sub3.example.com => (192.168.0.1:8002, 192.168.0.2:9002, 192.168.0.3:10002)
```

Now i'm trying to proxy all requests for sub1.example.com to one server in the list of associated servers.  The list is not static.

New servers can be added on the fly, dead ones can be removed imediately. I think it's ok for the first time to rely on round robin for selecting the matching backend server.

I've tried to modify nginx to do this job, but without success.  I'm not shure if haproxy can handle a dynamic list of backend and frontendservers?  perlbal can not select the routing file with the backend servers based on the request host.

Thanks in Advance,
Marc

Answer (score 1):

[Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/) can do it by poundctl program.